# Is it possible to move the "box" of a checkbox?

Tags: html, css

Currently when you make a checkbox, the "box" is to the left of the text.  Is it possible to adjust the orientation for:

1: vertical (above):

2: vertical (below):

3: horizontal (to the right of the text):

?

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tNS2N/)?

Comment: Yes,   So you are using breaks to place it above and bleow, and the ordering of the <input> vs the <label> is what determines the placement?

Comment: Yeah, it's just like text. I enter the words in the order I want them to appear. For above/below, you can use breaks or any element that displays as a `block`. The CSS property [`display:block`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp). These elements basically don't allow things to be on their sides. It's either above or below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input checkbox does not have connection to the text.

Box on the left:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="v[]" value="1"> 1
<input type="checkbox" name="v[]" value="2"> 2
<input type="checkbox" name="v[]" value="3"> 3
```

Box on the right:

```
1 <input type="checkbox" name="v[]" value="1">
2 <input type="checkbox" name="v[]" value="2">
3 <input type="checkbox" name="v[]" value="3">
```

If you are going to put it below or above, maybe you can create a table like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ONE</td>
        <td>II</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="v[]" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="v[]" value="2"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="v[]" value="3"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this?

```
<label>This is a checkbox: <input type="checkbox" /></label>
```